# dialog flow v2 code not running

Tags: webhooks, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I was testing the new code according to v2. Link: [Build Your First App with Dialogflow](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/first-app) 
code:

```
'use strict';

const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  console.log("-----welcome intent-----");
  conv.ask('Welcome');
});

exports.testMain = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

But when I simulate it, it shows :

```
MalformedResponse
'final_response' must be set.
```

What can I do?
The request is not reaching the function though Fulfillment is enabled.

**---------UPDATED------------**

now I am getting this error when I try to deploy the function to firebase:

```
Function load error: Code in file index.js can't be loaded
Is there a syntax error in your code?
Detailed stack trace: TypeError: dialogflow is not a funct
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/index.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at getUserFunction (/var/tmp/worker/worker.js:388:24)
    at loadUserCode (/var/tmp/worker/worker.js:444:18)
```

I am unable to understand???

Here is my **package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "some name",
  "description": "some desc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Google Inc.",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.0",
    "dialogflow": "^0.3.0",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

------update 2------
I have changed node to :

```
"engines": {
        "node": "~6.0"
```

still same problem

**-----Update 3--------**

Deployment complete, but when the request goes to it, it shows:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what version of node you're using. The package.json suggests that you're using node 4, when you need to be using at least node 6 if you're using `=>`.

Since Firebase Cloud Functions is node 6 as well, you should likely switch to it for your local development as well. (Node itself is at version 8 for LTS, and working on version 9, so you should certainly consider updating.)

Comment: I am using node v9.11.1

Answer (score 1):

Confirm which version of the actions-on-google library you're using. Your dependencies of `"actions-on-google": "^1.0.0"` specifies version 1.x of the library, but the rest of your usage is via the 2.0.0 syntax. The error suggests that there is no `dialogflow` object, which is also provided in version 2 of the library, but not version 1.

To use version 2.0.0 and up, you need to change the line in your package.json to

```
"actions-on-google": "^2.0.0"
```

and then run

```
npm update
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `fulfillment` is enable in the Dialogflow dashboard and that `v2` of the API is **turned on**? Also check that the intent name you are using in your fulfillment matches the one in Dialogflow.

Your code looks good to me. Its probably a configuration issue.

Comment: All is set, but not working, and now I am getting the new error

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing `conv.ask('Welcome')` to `conv.close('Welcome');`

also remove  `console.log("-----welcome intent-----");` line just for testing

Answer (score 0):

changed the package.json:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "~6.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.0.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.11.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.0",
    "dialogflow": "^0.3.0",
    "request": "^2.85.0",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1"
  }
```

And this works